# How to ensure single running process on a distributed environment

Tags: java, message, quartz

On a distributed environment I have many nodes running the same code.
I have a process that handles an event and I want to make sure it is only handled once.

What are the recomended solutions for this requirement?

Here are my options from the top of my head:

1. Using a message broker (RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Kafka).
   for instance, creating only one queue for this message.
   But I don't like adding another component to the stack.

   I dont really like adding a message brokers to the stack just for process sync.
2. use quartz.
   http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering .
   But I need a shared DB.

What are my other options?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Do you have the option to make it idempotent instead? Then an occasional doubling up just doesn't matter. If the event itself matters then  a messaging option using persistence is a good idea.

Comment: See also Apache ZooKeeper.

Comment: Forget your technical stack. Start with the business side of things. What is the importance of the event? Financial? And for errors what is the impact, who needs to know, who can act to resolve a problem.

Comment: How do you dispatch events and how does nodes access to these events?